# Flutter Doctor found issues:Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter Development. I have just started. I took up the Introduction to Flutter course by App Brewery. I followed all the steps as per the instructions given on the course and also from the flutter.dev website.After running the

`C:\Users\hashim irfan>flutter doctor`

in command prompt. The output given was

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.752], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

How do I solve this issue?

I have also attached a screenshot of the cmd screen for reference.
[Error:flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhMBS.jpg)

---

UPDATE #1:
I tried to execute this command too :

`C:\Users\hashim irfan>flutter doctor --android-licenses`

The output I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
```

I have attached that error here:[Error:flutter doctor --android-licenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwTBx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following in the command prompt: 
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Then, you will be shown the following: `Do you want to review the licenses?`

Enter `y` to confirm all licenses and then run `flutter doctor` again.

Comment: I am still getting an error. I have edited the above post attached the error I got above.